# dropdown div hidden when inside table tr

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if there is another post similar to this one but I'm hoping this can be a simple fix for someone better as css than me.

See the example here: https://svelte.dev/repl/e7d663de324043f98613b8fe35b8d78f?version=3.47.0

I build the example in Svelte repl but the issue is with the html and css.
The problem is that the dropdown part of the SimpleSelector is hidden behind the other rows below it.

I've tried to set the z-order but that doesn't seem to work. I tried playing with the display attribute and position but I can't seem to get this to work the way I want.

Try clicking on the textbox on any row. You'll see part of the dropdown but the rest is hidden.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does it have to be a table? Styling tables can be tricky and tables should only be used for displaying data .

Comment: The example in the repl is a watered down example of the full page being built. It's part of a page with search criteria at the top. When the user clicks search, the query is run and the results displayed in the table. There are a number of fixed columns (i.e. pinned to the left side) and the header row is also fixed (sticky). The user has the option to edit one row at a time where a number of cells change to editable text boxes and a few change to the SimpleSelector (dropdown). The page is designed for power data entry and I think a table is the best solution but I am open to ideas.

Comment: The problem is due to the select being inside a table cell. Increase the height of the rows and you'll see it becomes visible. I recommend you set up a simplified example which illustrates the problem and include this code in the question

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll try a simpler example and update my question.

Comment: You should probably add  `overflow: visible` somewhere

Comment: The problem is `.fixed-col {position: sticky;}`

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I will give them a try but I'm pretty sure I tried them during my many iterations. I'm in the process of creating a simpler example. I'm a little slammed with other things but I'll post an update as soon as I can get that new sample done. Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Ok. I have an updated simplified example here: https://svelte.dev/repl/70916fbeeec5458390fb8348b7b243ce?version=3.48.0

The issue is definitely linked to position:sticky. If you comment out the style for td, it works - the dropdown is visible. But when that style is in effect, the dropdown is hidden. 

Is there a way around this?
Thanks again for your help :o)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
It seems that the z-index had to be set separately for each row.
For example, if there are 100 rows, the first row should have z-index: 100, the second row, z-index: 99, the third, z-index: 98 and so on.
That seemed to have done the trick.
Here is a link to the updated REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/e84a80ef53a64af6975705407ddff040?version=3.48.0

However, in the end, I redesigned how the interface will work and I will not be editing inline in the table anymore so I won't be using this solution.